# How to add button after last row first column and also on top of last column?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table created using JavaScript. I want to append buttons after the last row of the first column and also on top of the last column.

```
for (var i = 0; i < responseData.length; i++) {
                for (var key in responseData[i]) {
                    if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                        col.push(key);
                    }
                }
            }
            console.log(col.length);

            var table = document.createElement("table");
            table.setAttribute('id', 'table');

            var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
            tr.setAttribute('id', 'tr');
            for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
                var th = document.createElement("th");
                th.setAttribute('id', 'th');
                th.innerHTML = col[i];
                tr.appendChild(th);
            }


            for (var i = 0; i < responseData.length; i++) {

                tr = table.insertRow(-1);

                for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                    var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                    tabCell.innerHTML = responseData[i][col[j]];
                }
            }
            var trr = table.insertRow(-1);
            var cell = trr.insertCell(-1);
            cell.append($('#addDeleteRow'))
                var divContainer = 
            document.getElementById("showData");
                divContainer.innerHTML = "";
                divContainer.appendChild(table);

               // 

     $('#addDeleteRow').insertAfter('#div').css({background:"yellow"})
            }
```

I Have tried it but the button is not aligned to table alignment

[image]

Comment: Exactly what HTML/DOM do you want to end up with?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea of how your responseData is structured,
but this code will help you solve your issue.

Plz note that you don't need that much ids and that ids are unique, so this line must be deleted: `th.setAttribute('id', 'th');`

Also notice that I'm cloning the button element with `var clone = $('.addDeleteRow').clone();`

```js
const responseData = [
 {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4},
 {'a': 5, 'b': 6, 'c': 7, 'd': 8}
];

var col = [];

for (var i = 0; i < responseData.length; i++) {
    for (var key in responseData[i]) {
        if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
            col.push(key);
        }
    }
}

var table = document.createElement("table");
var th;
var tr = table.insertRow(-1);
var cell;

for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerText = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
}


for (var i = 0; i < responseData.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);
    for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
        cell = tr.insertCell(-1);
        cell.innerText = responseData[i][col[j]];
    }
}

tr = table.insertRow(-1);
cell = tr.insertCell(-1);

var clone = $('.addDeleteRow').clone();
clone.css({background: 'yellow'});
clone.appendTo(cell);

var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
divContainer.innerHTML = "";
divContainer.appendChild(table);

$('.addDeleteRow').on('click', function () {
  console.log('add/delete');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="addDeleteRow">Add/Delete</button>
<div id="showData"></div>
```

Comment: but how to remove the css for only that cell created?

Comment: I updated the answer, you can use `clone.css({background: 'yellow'})`. Why the downvote????

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? Not sure what you dataset looks like, so didn't the conditions.

You can adjust the css if needed.

```js
var dataSets = [{
  ant: "Red",
  bison: "Black",
  camel: "Black",
  duck: "Grey"

}, {
  ant: "Black",
  bison: "Brown",
  camel: "Brown",
  duck: "White"

}];

// $.get(url, function(data) {}).done(function(responseData) {
var table = "<tr><th>new Column0</th><th>new Column1</th><th>new Column2</th></tr>";
for (var elem of dataSets /*reponseData*/ ) {
//  console.log(elem);
  table += "<tr><td>" + elem.ant + "</td><td>" + elem.bison + "</td><td>" + elem.camel + "</td></tr>";
}
var i = 0;
document.getElementById("tableID").innerHTML = table;

$("#tableID")[0].insertRow(0).setAttribute("id", "first");
$("#tableID")[0].insertRow(-1).setAttribute("id", "last");

while (i < 3) {
  $("#first")[0].insertCell(i).setAttribute("id", "first" + i);
  $("#last")[0].insertCell(i).setAttribute("id", "last" + i);
  ++i;
}

$("#first2")[0].innerHTML = "<button>First</button>";
$("#last0")[0].innerHTML = "<button>Last</button>";

// });
```

```css
table,
th,
tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showData">
  <table id="tableID"></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can add a new row and make the corresponding cell a button.

```
<tr>
  <td class="style it like a button" onclick="doSomething()">button name</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```